# PUSH ERRORReceived an error with invalid JSON from Parse after successful parse push send

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, parse-server

After successful push send the following error prevents push to be sent:

```
0|parse-wr | #### PUSH ERRORReceived an error with invalid JSON from Parse: <html>
0|parse-wr | <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
0|parse-wr | <body bgcolor="white">
0|parse-wr | <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
0|parse-wr | <hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
0|parse-wr | </body>
0|parse-wr | </html>
```

This happened after I changed my ubuntu server DNS here is my nginx sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
        root /mnt/psapp/;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name psappco.ir www.psappco.ir;

        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
         }
        # location /test {
          # root /mnt/psapp;
        # }
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/psappco.ir/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/psappco.ir/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot
    location /parse/ {
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                # WebSocket support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
        location /dashboard/ {
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:4040/dashboard/;
         proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_redirect off;
        }
        client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

should I add something related to push adapter in nginx ,I 've activated ssl using lets encrypt.
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
parse-server version 2.3.8
cloud code which I've used is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('driveRequest', function(request, response) {
    // request has 2 parameters: params passed by the client and the authorized user
    var params = request.params;
    var user = request.user;
    // extract out the channel to send
    var action = params.action;
    var launch = params.launch;
    // use to custom tweak whatever payload you wish to send
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    var driverQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    driverQuery.equalTo("isonline",true);
    driverQuery.equalTo("riderordriver","driver");
    //var nearbyDriversQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    var riderLocation = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: params.riderLatitude, longitude: params.riderLongitude});
    driverQuery.withinKilometers("location",riderLocation,2.0);
    //var driverQuery = Parse.Query.or(nearbyDriversQuery,isOnlineQuery);
    pushQuery.matchesQuery('users',driverQuery);
   // pushQuery.matchesQuery('isonlineusers',isOnlineQuery);
    var payload = {
        "action": action,
        "launch": launch,
    };

    // Note that useMasterKey is necessary for Push notifications to succeed.

    Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: payload
    }, { success: function() {
        console.log("#### PUSH OK");
    }, error: function(error) {
        console.log("#### PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
    },useMasterKey:true});
    response.success('success');
});
```

And ParseServer index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');  
var path = require('path');
var FSStoreAdapter = require('parse-server-fs-store-adapter');
var fs_store_adapter = new FSStoreAdapter({
    filesSubDirectory: "/root/parsefiles" 
});
//var Parse = require('parse/node').Parse;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var pushConfig = {};

if (process.env.GCM_SENDER_ID && process.env.GCM_API_KEY) {
    pushConfig['android'] = { senderId: process.env.GCM_SENDER_ID || 'my sender id',
                              apiKey: process.env.GCM_API_KEY || 'my key'};
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/taxifinder',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'My app_ID',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'My master key', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  push: pushConfig,
  filesAdapter: fs_store_adapter,
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https/localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['Test'],
    redisURL: 'redis://localhost:6379'
  },
  maxUploadSize: "100mb"
});
var app = express();
// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
//app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 // res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
//      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
//});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer,{
        redisURL: 'redis://localhost:6379'
});

var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({  
  "apps": [{
      "serverURL": 'https://psappco.ir/parse', // Not localhost
      "appId": 'my app id',
      "masterKey": 'My master key',
      "appName": "PSAPP",
      "production": false,
      "iconName": "app-icon.png",
  }],
  "users": [
    {
      "user":"---",
      "pass":"----"
    }
  ],
  "iconsFolder": "icons"
});

var dashApp = express();

// make the Parse Dashboard available at /dashboard
dashApp.use('/dashboard', dashboard);  

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
dashApp.get('/', function(req, res) {  
  res.status(200).send('Parse Dashboard App');
});

var httpServerDash = require('http').createServer(dashApp);  
httpServerDash.listen(4040, function() {  
    console.log('dashboard-server running on port 4040.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to your configuration. What is the value of `SERVER_URL`? Does it contain `/parse`?